# Exclude not null and less than condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

I need to sort out data into 2 reports for oracle report. Below is my query to sort out everything. For now I need to exclude all data that is shown in other report with following condition

generally I would like to exclude `client_no` that is not in value in this condition

```
WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND **CHQ_AMT>50000**)
or (CATEGORY='3' AND **CHQ_AMT>10000**))
```

**1. FIRST REPORT**

`WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT>50000)
or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT>10000))`

For second report I used the below condition and it must exclude condition from first report.

**SECOND REPORT**
`WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000)
or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000))`

Below is my coding and need to add condition to exclude report 1

```
SELECT CLIENT_NO,
       sum(decode(category,'3',decode(nvl(cancel_flag,'N'),'N',1,-2) ,0)) CASH,
       sum(decode(chq_no, null,0, decode(nvl(cancel_flag,'N'),'N',1,-2))) CHQ,
       0 YTD_PURCHASE,
       0 YTD_SALES,
       0  CURRENT_CRLIMIT,
       0 CR_LIMIT 
FROM BOS_M_LEDGER_REC 
WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000)) 
and CLIENT_NO>=:P_CLIENT_NO_FROM 
AND CLIENT_NO <=:P_CLIENT_NO_TO 
AND TRAN_DATE>=:P_FROM_DATE 
AND TRAN_DATE<=:P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY CLIENT_NO
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag as this is clearly Oracle.

Comment: You can try a sub-query to exclude the clients present in first query.

Comment: `WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000)) ` Isn't this condition already removing `client_no` present in Report 1? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tq

Comment: @Vashi its already removes but i have another report. thats why i have to exclude for this rport only. total i have 3 report.

Comment: Do you have a table available that has `client_no` of Report 1?

Comment: hi, @Vashi for example this client_no `3VI0555' Already come out in report 1 with  the condition above. but in report 2 also got it because this client_no also have cheque <50k. should be, when come out in 1st report, no need to show in 2nd report even the cheque condition is  true. so i need to exclude this client_no from report 2. tq

Comment: If I understand correctly, a `client_no` can have more than one `chq_amt` values and if some `client_no` has a `chq_amt`>50k meaning that it is in Report 1, then that `client_no` should not show in Report 2 even if other `chq_amt`<50k for that same `client_no`. And you want to remove such `client_no` from the above query. Is that correct?

Comment: @Vashi yes .exactly what i want. i still figure out. i do this,but the result is not what i want   `WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000)
 or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000)
 or (CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT>50000)
 or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT>10000))`

Comment: For simplicity, do you have report 1 and report 2 tables available? If you already have these tables, then you can remove `client_no` present in report 1 from the report 2 table using left join. I think it would be much easier to remove through a left join instead of editing the WHERE condition based on your requirements. Let me know if you have these tables available OR if you can at least create them separately.

Comment: @Vashi this is company database and i cannot simply create new table. so i just only can called all the data and query based on user request to create a report. anyways i try to used the left join first.tq for suggestion.

Comment: Hi @RajatMishra, can you suggest me the subquery. i try this but error  `WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000)
or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000))
and (select CLIENT_NO FROM BOS_M_CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_NO NOT IN (SELECT CLIENT_NO FROM BOS_M_CLIENT WHERE((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT>50000)
or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT>10000)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the logic to remove those `client_no` in report 1 in the subquery represented by the alias `B`. Used that list of `client_no` in `B` in a full outer join on `client_no` with your original table(report 2 with the alias `A`). This will create NULLs in both A.client_no and B.client_no columns wherever there is a mismatch.

Then added a `WHERE B.CLIENT_NO IS NULL` which means you will only have `client_no` that are in `A` and not in `B`[FYI if B.client_no is not NULL, that means there is a match with A.client_no and you don't want that client_no in report 3].

I have not made changes at other places in the query.

```
SELECT A.CLIENT_NO,
    sum(decode(category,'3',decode(nvl(cancel_flag,'N'),'N',1,-2) ,0)) CASH,
    sum(decode(chq_no, null,0, decode(nvl(cancel_flag,'N'),'N',1,-2))) CHQ,
    0 YTD_PURCHASE,
    0 YTD_SALES,
    0  CURRENT_CRLIMIT,
    0 CR_LIMIT 
FROM BOS_M_LEDGER_REC A
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT CLIENT_NO FROM BOS_M_LEDGER_REC WHERE ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT>=50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT>=10000)) GROUP BY CLIENT_NO) B
ON A.CLIENT_NO = B.CLIENT_NO
WHERE B.CLIENT_NO IS NULL
AND ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000)) 
AND A.CLIENT_NO>=:P_CLIENT_NO_FROM 
AND A.CLIENT_NO <=:P_CLIENT_NO_TO 
AND TRAN_DATE>=:P_FROM_DATE 
AND TRAN_DATE<=:P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY A.CLIENT_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that your code as it currently is excludes cheque amounts that are exactly 50,000 or 10,000 from both reports, because neither includes an exact match on those values - one report selects values above, and the other below. I don't know whether this is intentional or an oversight in the logic.

```
WITH common_report_subquery AS
(
    SELECT 
        CLIENT_NO

        ,DECODE(
                category
                ,'3', DECODE(
                            NVL(cancel_flag, 'N')
                            ,'N', 1
                            ,-2
                            ) 
                ,0
            ) AS CASH

        ,DECODE(
                chq_no
                ,NULL, 0
                ,DECODE(
                        NVL(cancel_flag, 'N')
                        ,'N', 1
                        ,-2
                        )
            ) AS CHQ


        ,IIF(
                ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT>50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT>10000))
                ,1
                ,0
            ) AS MEETS_FIRST_REPORT_CRITERIA

        ,IIF(
                ((CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND CHQ_AMT<50000) or (CATEGORY='3' AND CHQ_AMT<10000))
                ,1
                ,0
            ) AS MEETS_SECOND_REPORT_CRITERIA


    FROM 
        BOS_M_LEDGER_REC 

    WHERE 
        ( CLIENT_NO BETWEEN :P_CLIENT_NO_FROM AND :P_CLIENT_NO_TO )
        AND 
        ( TRAN_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE )
)

,first_report AS
(
    SELECT
        CLIENT_NO
        ,SUM(CASH) AS CASH
        ,SUM(CHQ) AS CHQ

        ,0 AS YTD_PURCHASE
        ,0 AS YTD_SALES
        ,0 AS CURRENT_CRLIMIT
        ,0 AS CR_LIMIT

    FROM
        common_report_subquery

    WHERE 
        (MEETS_FIRST_REPORT_CRITERIA = 1) 

    GROUP BY 
        CLIENT_NO

)

,second_report_subquery AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,MAX(MEETS_FIRST_REPORT_CRITERIA) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_NO ORDER BY NULL) AS CLIENT_APPEARS_ON_FIRST_REPORT

    FROM
        common_report_subquery

)

,second_report AS
(
    SELECT
        CLIENT_NO
        ,SUM(CASH) AS CASH
        ,SUM(CHQ) AS CHQ

        ,0 AS YTD_PURCHASE
        ,0 AS YTD_SALES
        ,0 AS CURRENT_CRLIMIT
        ,0 AS CR_LIMIT

    FROM
        second_report_subquery

    WHERE 
        (MEETS_SECOND_REPORT_CRITERIA = 1)
        AND
        --excludes consideration of any rows for clients that met the criteria for inclusion on the first report
        (CLIENT_APPEARS_ON_FIRST_REPORT = 0) 

    GROUP BY 
        CLIENT_NO
)

--uncomment the relevant line below for each report
--SELECT * FROM first_report
--SELECT * FROM second_report
```